# Disable one JButton when another JBUtton is enabled

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I'm trying to build a simple rolling dice game for my assignment. There will be 2 players. In my code I try to use method `getSource()` so that when a player `roll` JButton is enabled, the other player's button will be disabled but when I run the game both player's buttons are still enabled. Here are my code:

Die.java

```
import java.util.*;
public class Die
{
    private final int MAX = 6;
    private int die1;
    Random rand = new Random();

    //Constructor
    public Die()
    {
        die1 = 1;
    }// end Constructor

    public int Roll()
    {
        die1 = rand.nextInt(MAX)+1;
        return die1;
    }
}
```

DisplaySixNumbersPanel.java

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class DisplaySixNumbersPanel
{
    public static void main(String[ ] args) 
    {
        JFrame w1 = new JFrame("Six Numbers Game");
        w1.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2));
        SixNumbersPanel2 player1 =new SixNumbersPanel2();
        SixNumbersPanel2 player2 =new SixNumbersPanel2();
        w1.add(player1);
        w1.add(player2);
        w1.setSize(540, 350);
        w1.setVisible(true);
        w1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    } //end main
} //end class
```

SixNumbersPanel2.java

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;

public class SixNumbersPanel2 extends JPanel implements ActionListener
{
    private JTextField text1;
    private boolean flag = false;
    private boolean checkflag[] = {false,false,false,false,false,false,false};
    private JLabel label;
    private JLabel label1;
    public JButton roll;
    private JButton restartButton;
    private JTextArea display;
    private JTextField[] fields = new JTextField[7];
    private Die dice = new Die();
    private int key;
    private int count;
    private int count1;
    private Player player1 = new Player();
    private Player player2 = new Player();
    private int check;
    private int[] list = new int [7];
    //private SixNumbersPanel2 player2panel;
    public SixNumbersPanel2()
    {
        label= new JLabel ("A number between 1 to 6 wil appear");
        label1 = new JLabel("once in each of the following textfields");
        roll = new JButton("Roll dice");
        restartButton = new JButton("Restart Game");
        text1 = new JTextField(3);
        display = new JTextArea(10,15);
        add(label);
        add(label1);
        for(int i=1;i<7;i++)
        {
            fields[i] = new JTextField(3);
            add(fields[i]);
        }
        add(roll);
        add(text1);
        add(display);
        display.setEditable(false);      
        restartButton.setVisible(false);
        add(restartButton);
        restartButton.addActionListener(this);
        roll.addActionListener(this);        
    }
    public void restart()
    {
       display.setText("");
       text1.setText("");
       for(int i=1; i<7; i++)
       {
           fields[i].setText("");
       }
       count=0;
       count1=0;
       Arrays.fill(checkflag,false);
       Arrays.fill(list,0);
       flag = false;
       restartButton.setVisible(false);
       rollenable(); 

    }


    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
    {
        if(event.getSource() == roll)
        {
            player2.rolldisable();
        }

        key=dice.Roll();
        count++;
        String toScreen= "Number of rolls: "+count;
        display.setText(toScreen);
        text1.setText(""+key);
        check = player1.Check(list,key);
        if(check < 0)
        {
            count1++;
            for(int i=1;i<7;i++)
            {
                if(key == i)
                {
                    list[i] = key;
                    checkflag[i]=true;
                    fields[i].setText(""+key);
                    if(checkflag[i] == true)
                    {
                        flag = true;
                        for(int a=1; a<7; a++)
                        {
                            if(checkflag[a]==false)
                            {
                                flag=false;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                if(flag == true)
                {
                    display.setText("Congratulation, you have \ntaken "+count+" rolls to get one of \neach number between 1 and 6");
                    rolldisable();
                    restartButton.setVisible(true);                   
                }
            }
        }
        if(event.getSource() == restartButton)
        {
            restart();
        }
    }
    public void rollenable()
    {
        roll.setEnabled(true);
    }
    public void rolldisable()
    {
        roll.setEnabled(false);
    }
    public JButton getSubButton()
    {
        return this.roll;
    }
}
```

Player.java

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class Player
{

    private final int MAX = 100;
    private Die play = new Die();
    private boolean[] results = {false,false,false,false,false,false,false};
    private int count;
    private int key;
    private boolean check = false;
    //private JButton roll;
    public Player()
    {
        count=0;
        key=0;
    }
    public void Play()
    {
        for(int i=0;i<MAX;i++)
        {
            key=play.Roll();
            System.out.print("\nNumber rolled: "+key); 
            count++; 
            for(int a=1;a<7;a++)
            {
                if(a==key)
                {
                    results[a]=true;
                    System.out.print("\nSo far, you have rolled ");  
                    if(results[a]==true)
                    {
                        check=true;
                        for(int k=1;k<7;k++)
                        {
                            if(results[k] ==true)
                        {
                            System.out.print(" "+k+" ");
                        }
                        if(results[k] == false)
                        check=false;
                        }
                    }        
                }
            }  
            if(check==true)
            {
                System.out.print("\nCongratulations, you have taken "+count+" rolls to get one of each number between 1 and 6");
                break;
            }         
        }             
    }

    public int Check(int []check,int key)
    {
        int check1= Arrays.binarySearch(check,key);
        return check1;   
    }

    //public JButton getButton()
    //{
       // JButton button = null;
        //SixNumbersPanel2 roll = new SixNumbersPanel2();
        //return roll.roll = button;
    //}
    public void rolldisable() 
    {
        SixNumbersPanel2 dis = new SixNumbersPanel2();
        dis.getSubButton().setEnabled(false);
    }
}
```

Also with the `restartButton` JButton, it doesn't restart the whole game but only for the player who clicks it. Any suggestion as how to make it restart the whole GUI would be awesome.

All helps would be appreciated.

Comment: Please spend some time at the [help] to learn how/what to ask here. You have pasted a lot of code - but this is not a community where people work with you through your problem. And unrelated: please read about "Clean Code". Your code is much more complicated and hard to read than it ought to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This...

```
public void rolldisable() 
{
    SixNumbersPanel2 dis = new SixNumbersPanel2();
    dis.getSubButton().setEnabled(false);
}
```

is wrong, basically you're creating a new instance of `SixNumbersPanel2` and are trying to change it's state, but it's not actually displayed on the screen nor does it have anything to do with what is displayed on the screen.

This solution is not a simple one.  What you need is some kind of model/controller which can be shared between the two instances of `SixNumbersPanel2` and which generate appropriate state events to which they can respond.

You will need to devise some way of identifying which player is which so each `SixNumbersPanel2` knows which player it represents and which player is currently active

## Updated...

In order to implement the function changes needed, you need some kind of "central" hub, which is managing the core functionality and which can generate notification/events when the state changes in some meaningful way (like the next players turn)

In broad terms, these are covered by:

- [Model-View-Controller](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=model+view+controller&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8)
- [Observer Patten](https://www.google.com/search?safe=off&client=safari&rls=en&ei=n6sHW-q7Ccbc0AS_0aqgDA&q=observer+pattern&oq=obs&gs_l=psy-ab.3.0.0i67k1l3j0i131i67k1l2j0i67k1j0j0i131k1l2j0.19728.21337.0.22512.7.6.1.0.0.0.300.901.0j2j1j1.4.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..2.5.915....0.QaRa6tZpr1E)

First, we need to start with some kind of token, to differentiate the players...

```
enum Player {
    ONE, TWO;
}
```

Next, we need some kind of "model", which is used to manage the data and the core functionality

```
public interface SixNumbersModel {        
    public Player getCurrentTurn();        
    public Player nextTurn();        
    public int roll();        
    public boolean hasWon(Player player);        
    public Set<Integer> getPlayerResults(Player player);
    public int getTurnsCount(Player player);        
    public void addChangeListener(ChangeListener listener);
    public void removeChangeListener(ChangeListener listener);
}
```

*nb: You could actually have a "player model" which managed the results, but I'm been lazy*

The reason I've started with a `interface` is users of the model should not care about how the model is implemented (implementations might seperate the management of each players results into individual models, but users of the `SixNumbersModel` won't care)

```
public class DefaultSizeNumbersModel implements SixNumbersModel {

    private List<ChangeListener> changeListeners;
    private Die die = new Die();

    private Player turn;

    private Map<Player, Set<Integer>> results;
    private Map<Player, Integer> turns;

    public DefaultSizeNumbersModel() {
        changeListeners = new ArrayList<>(2);
        results = new HashMap<>();
        results.put(Player.ONE, new HashSet<>(6));
        results.put(Player.TWO, new HashSet<>(6));
        turns = new HashMap<>(2);
        turns.put(Player.ONE, 0);
        turns.put(Player.TWO, 0);
        setCurrentTurn(Player.ONE);
    }

    @Override
    public Player getCurrentTurn() {
        return turn;
    }

    protected void setCurrentTurn(Player player) {
        turn = player;
    }

    @Override
    public Player nextTurn() {
        switch (getCurrentTurn()) {
            case ONE:
                setCurrentTurn(Player.TWO);
                break;
            case TWO:
                setCurrentTurn(Player.ONE);
                break;
            default:
                setCurrentTurn(Player.ONE);
                break;
        }
        fireStateChanged();
        return getCurrentTurn();
    }

    @Override
    public int roll() {
        incrementTurnCount(getCurrentTurn());
        int result = die.Roll();
        Set<Integer> playerResults = results.get(getCurrentTurn());
        playerResults.add(result);
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasWon(Player player) {
        Set<Integer> playerResults = results.get(getCurrentTurn());
        return playerResults.size() == 5; // 0...5
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Integer> getPlayerResults(Player player) {
        Set<Integer> actualResults = results.get(player);
        Set<Integer> copy = new HashSet<>(actualResults);
        return copy;
    }

    @Override
    public int getTurnsCount(Player player) {
        return turns.get(player);
    }

    protected void setTurnsCount(Player player, int count) {
        turns.put(player, count);
    }

    protected void incrementTurnCount(Player player) {
        int count = getTurnsCount(player);
        count++;
        setTurnsCount(player, count);
    }

    @Override
    public void addChangeListener(ChangeListener listener) {
        changeListeners.add(listener);
    }

    @Override
    public void removeChangeListener(ChangeListener listener) {
        changeListeners.remove(listener);
    }

    protected void fireStateChanged() {
        ChangeEvent evt = new ChangeEvent(this);
        for (ChangeListener listener : changeListeners) {
            listener.stateChanged(evt);
        }
    }
}
```

Then we need some kind of "view"...

```
public class SixNumbersPanel extends JPanel {

    private Player player;
    private SixNumbersModel model;

    private JButton roll;
    private JTextArea ta;

    public SixNumbersPanel(Player player, SixNumbersModel model) {
        this.player = player;
        this.model = model;

        model.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                roll.setEnabled(player == model.getCurrentTurn());
            }
        });

        roll = new JButton("Roll");
        ta = new JTextArea(5, 10);

        roll.setEnabled(player == model.getCurrentTurn());

        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
        add(new JLabel(player.name()), gbc);
        add(roll, gbc);

        gbc.weightx = 1;
        gbc.weighty = 1;
        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        add(new JScrollPane(ta), gbc);

        roll.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                int result = model.roll();
                ta.append(Integer.toString(result) + "\n");
                if (model.hasWon(player)) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(SixNumbersPanel.this, player + " has won");
                }
                model.nextTurn();
            }
        });

    }

}
```

Okay, massively basic, but, it simply has a button and a text area.  It registers interest to the model to be notified when the state changes and makes sure that the button is only enabled when the player it represents is the current player.

[image: Rolly Polly]

## Runnable example...

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    enum Player {
        ONE, TWO;
    }

    public interface SixNumbersModel {

        public Player getCurrentTurn();

        public Player nextTurn();

        public int roll();

        public boolean hasWon(Player player);

        public Set<Integer> getPlayerResults(Player player);

        public int getTurnsCount(Player player);

        public void addChangeListener(ChangeListener listener);

        public void removeChangeListener(ChangeListener listener);
    }

    public class DefaultSizeNumbersModel implements SixNumbersModel {

        private List<ChangeListener> changeListeners;
        private Die die = new Die();

        private Player turn;

        private Map<Player, Set<Integer>> results;
        private Map<Player, Integer> turns;

        public DefaultSizeNumbersModel() {
            changeListeners = new ArrayList<>(2);
            results = new HashMap<>();
            results.put(Player.ONE, new HashSet<>(6));
            results.put(Player.TWO, new HashSet<>(6));
            turns = new HashMap<>(2);
            turns.put(Player.ONE, 0);
            turns.put(Player.TWO, 0);
            setCurrentTurn(Player.ONE);
        }

        @Override
        public Player getCurrentTurn() {
            return turn;
        }

        protected void setCurrentTurn(Player player) {
            turn = player;
        }

        @Override
        public Player nextTurn() {
            switch (getCurrentTurn()) {
                case ONE:
                    setCurrentTurn(Player.TWO);
                    break;
                case TWO:
                    setCurrentTurn(Player.ONE);
                    break;
                default:
                    setCurrentTurn(Player.ONE);
                    break;
            }
            fireStateChanged();
            return getCurrentTurn();
        }

        @Override
        public int roll() {
            incrementTurnCount(getCurrentTurn());
            int result = die.Roll();
            Set<Integer> playerResults = results.get(getCurrentTurn());
            playerResults.add(result);
            return result;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasWon(Player player) {
            Set<Integer> playerResults = results.get(getCurrentTurn());
            return playerResults.size() == 5; // 0...5
        }

        @Override
        public Set<Integer> getPlayerResults(Player player) {
            Set<Integer> actualResults = results.get(player);
            Set<Integer> copy = new HashSet<>(actualResults);
            return copy;
        }

        @Override
        public int getTurnsCount(Player player) {
            return turns.get(player);
        }

        protected void setTurnsCount(Player player, int count) {
            turns.put(player, count);
        }

        protected void incrementTurnCount(Player player) {
            int count = getTurnsCount(player);
            count++;
            setTurnsCount(player, count);
        }

        @Override
        public void addChangeListener(ChangeListener listener) {
            changeListeners.add(listener);
        }

        @Override
        public void removeChangeListener(ChangeListener listener) {
            changeListeners.remove(listener);
        }

        protected void fireStateChanged() {
            ChangeEvent evt = new ChangeEvent(this);
            for (ChangeListener listener : changeListeners) {
                listener.stateChanged(evt);
            }
        }
    }

    public class Die {

        private final int MAX = 6;
        private int die1;
        Random rand = new Random();

        //Constructor
        public Die() {
            die1 = 1;
        }// end Constructor

        public int Roll() {
            die1 = rand.nextInt(MAX) + 1;
            return die1;
        }
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Roll Six");
                frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 0));

                SixNumbersModel model = new DefaultSizeNumbersModel();
                SixNumbersPanel onePane = new SixNumbersPanel(Player.ONE, model);
                SixNumbersPanel twoPane = new SixNumbersPanel(Player.TWO, model);

                frame.add(onePane);
                frame.add(twoPane);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class SixNumbersPanel extends JPanel {

        private Player player;
        private SixNumbersModel model;

        private JButton roll;
        private JTextArea ta;

        public SixNumbersPanel(Player player, SixNumbersModel model) {
            this.player = player;
            this.model = model;

            model.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                    roll.setEnabled(player == model.getCurrentTurn());
                }
            });

            roll = new JButton("Roll");
            ta = new JTextArea(5, 10);

            roll.setEnabled(player == model.getCurrentTurn());

            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
            add(new JLabel(player.name()), gbc);
            add(roll, gbc);

            gbc.weightx = 1;
            gbc.weighty = 1;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
            add(new JScrollPane(ta), gbc);

            roll.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    int result = model.roll();
                    ta.append(Integer.toString(result) + "\n");
                    if (model.hasWon(player)) {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(SixNumbersPanel.this, player + " has won");
                    }
                    model.nextTurn();
                }
            });

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: I changed `flag` in `SixNumbersPanel` from `private` to `public`, then built a nested loop in `DisplaySixNumbersPanel` with the condition `while(player1.flag == false || player2.flag == false)`, an if loop will run so that if one player's button is pressed, that button will then be disabled and enable the other player's. However when I run it seems the nested loop didn't seem to have any effects on the GUI. Can you please tell me what I mistake I made here? Thank you

Comment: @TerrenceChu Most GUI frameworks are single threaded. Using a "loop" to control conditions is dangerous and ill-advised. I've updated the answer with a "concept" of one way of solving your problem